# Java or Spring code to download package from nexus

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, curl, nexus

Is there a way I can connect to my Nexus repot from Java or Spring and download package. Something like Restapi would be great.

For e.g. I want to write a function which download artifact from nexus if I provide it the groupid, atifact-id and file name etc.

file_name = download_from_nexus(group_id, artifact-id, name-of-file, file-format)

I tried searching on google but cannot find any ready made library or solution which could be used.

Is this possible?

Many Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Change your settings in .m2 to point at your nexus repository and mvn clean install?

Comment: Yeah that way is possible, but how to download packages at runtime based on what is passed as parameter. I have to write some automation framework, where I download some package from nexus and deploy it later on some remote machine and do further processing.

other option would be to use CURL within  java code, creating a URL object and connecting to NEXUS, but I wanted to know if there is any ready made API or REST Server or a Spring Feature which can be used, instead of writing a function from scratch.

Comment: From your parameters you could build a curl command that downloads the package. So a general HTTP client for Java should do the trick.

Comment: I recommend to take a look at: https://maven.apache.org/resolver/ or why not using Maven?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the API: https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/REST+and+Integration+API

You can try to access it directly by crafting the right URL: `http://{nexus.hostname}/repository/{repository.name}/{groupId}/{artifactId}/{version}/{artifactId}-{version}.jar`
(example: `http://nexus.local/repository/maven-public/antlr/antlr/2.7.2/antlr-2.7.2.jar`)

Answer (score 0):

in alternative to the REST Api, you can also follow this process to generate a Java Client API from the Swagger-UI interface available in Nexus 3.14

http://www.javamonamour.org/2018/05/swagger-editor-and-generation-of-java.html

The SearchAPI class has a method searchAndDownloadAssets, this will download the file to a tmp folder that you can set with SearchAPI.getApiClient().setTempFolderPath(...)